# What is the fastest way to move in Borderlands 3?

Tags: borderlands-3

There are 3 primary types of movement in borderlands 3:

- Sprinting
- Jumping
- Sliding

Optimizing your character's movement speed is essential for making legendary farming routes as seamless and efficient as possible. In Borderlands 3, the addition of the sliding mechanic introduces a whole new dimension to the game. **This begs the question, how do all these movement mechanics come together in-game? And what combination of movements will allow you to move the quickest?**

> *A few guiding questions to address:*
>
> 1. Does sliding actually increase one's movement speed? (when one does not consider any relevant gear)
> 2. Is sliding downhill faster than doing so on level surfaces? Consequently, does sliding uphill slow you down?
> 3. If sliding (without mods) increases your movement speed, what can I make of the prompt during loading screens that states that sliding
>      does not make you any faster than sprinting? Is it just a lie?
> 4. What combination of movement is the fastest? (2 answers, one with gear and one without)
> 5. What is the fastest way to move in low-gravity environments like Skywell-27?
> 6. Do the different characters and their varying movement mechanics affect the answer in no.4?

Comment: _"If [this] is true, what can I make of [that which contradicts this]"_ is a really weird question to ask. Obviously, the latter is then provably incorrect when you assume that the former is true.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Does sliding actually increase one's movement speed? (when one does
>   not consider any relevant gear)

- Sliding does not increase movement speed. This is known from both [this test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tX4T8znJd2U), my own knowledge and a loading screen in-game that actually comments saying 'sliding only feels faster but actually isn't' (paraphrased). (It does appear he ends timers a bit off and that they're all essentially the same time)
- ArrowCase in the comments is suggesting if you time it properly you can actually slide faster than running.

> Is sliding downhill faster than doing so on level surfaces?
>   Consequently, does sliding uphill slow you down?

- From my own experiences, sliding uphill does slow you down, the slide ends quickly as there is resistance to sliding upwards. Sliding down does speed you up, you accelerate down the hill and can hold the slide for a longer period of time.

> If sliding (without mods) increases your movement speed, what can I
>   make of the prompt during loading screens that states that sliding
>   does not make you any faster than sprinting? Is it just a lie?

- It is telling the truth.

> What combination of movement is the fastest? (2 answers, one with gear
>   and one without)

**Without gear:**

- Without modifications or character boosts, only sliding downhill will help you move faster.
- As noted by Jutschge, running with a rocket launcher will slow you down.

**With gear, you can slide around much faster:**

- You can utilize the [Vanquisher](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Vanquisher_(Borderlands_3)) smg to increase slide speed. (20% buff)
- You can utilize various artifacts that boost slide speed. Artifact use can be seen in the test video above and also in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/borderlands3/comments/d4boc7/epic_artifact_with_103_slide_speed/). (Upwards of 105% I've seen)
- There are also shields that give out speed boosts when you are at full shields. (Usually 10%)
- Various character perks allow for boosted movement speed. Including Amara mindfulness stacks and Zane's speed buffs (drone-based)

> What is the fastest way to move in low-gravity environments like
>   Skywell-27?

- The low gravity doesn't impact speeds as far as I can tell. It is mainly helpful in allowing you to jump to places you normally couldn't. I typically jumped around in skywell but I believe it falls under the "feels faster but actually isn't" comment.

> Do the different characters and their varying movement mechanics
>   affect the answer in no.4?

- No, their **base** speeds are all the same. Only movement mechanics I've witnessed as varying are vaulting/climbing around. (Moze is better at getting into/onto small things)
- However, as seen [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/borderlands3/comments/cugtif/best_character_for_movement_speed/) you can boost character movements based off their skill trees. (Things in parentheses are my additions)

> Amara: 10% on kill with her action skill
>   4.2% when hit, stacking 25 times (You can shoot yourself via a rocket, grenades, etc to boost your speed yourself)
>
> Zane: 12% per active action skill 20% after kill 5% after kill from
>   empowering the above skill via Death Follows Close 6% per enemy
>   weakened by SNTNL 11% after touching Barrier
>
> Moze: 25% in Iron Bear after hitting with Salamander
>
> Fl4k: 5% permanent with Jabber pet 5% permanent via doubling pet
>   bonuses with Barbaric Yawp 25% in Fade Away 10% while above half
>   health
>
> With no enemies around, like backtracking in an area, Fl4k has the
>   upper hand. 20% "permanent", and an extra 25% for up to 32.5 of every
>   45 seconds.
>
> Zane can get up to 35% out of combat depending on his action skill
>   rotation.
>
> Amara and Moze have no movement speed (bonuses) outside of combat.
>
> In combat, Zane and Amara pull ahead. Amara likely has the easiest to
>   reach potential, but Zane does not rely on being hit. Additionally,
>   his SNTNL beam buff has no cap, but it's unknown how practical it will
>   be to get many stacks.
>
> TL:DR, Fl4k if there's nothing to shoot at or get shot by, Amara if
>   you're trying to run past enemies shooting at you, Zane if you want to
>   go fast in combat, but are avoiding being shot at.

Comment: Great answer. Some things I'd suggest adding though: With Amara you can easily boost your MS if you manage to proc an elemental status effect on yourself to quickly stack up Mindfulness out of combat (either through a barrel, grenade or weapon with splash damage). Also it's not an increase but carrying a rocket launcher will slow you down (idk by how much though).

Comment: The reddit thread that explained all those character boosts had some stuff about Amara boosting herself, so I can add that. 
I thought rockets slowed you down but I hadn't tested it, I'll add it.

Comment: With Amara, you can also trigger the mindfulness stack with some decorations elements that can damage you, as torches. You may not go to full-stack in a blink of eyes with this, but it doesn't take your time shooting or throwing a grenade and you can just run through them to gain a little boost without stop running/sliding. It's not really worth adding in the answer, but I wanted to mention this little tip. (By the way, moving Amara at 25 stacks is pretty impressive, and it may be hard to aim at very close range until you're used to it).

Comment: Do any of the billions of guns give speed buffs?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the 'Vanquisher' Legendary SMG gives a 20% sliding speed boost. No other guns I've noticed/read give speed boosts. And as Jutschge mentioned, rocket launchers will make you run a bit slower.

Comment: There's a glitch with Moze I found that seems to be able to get you infinitely increasing movement speed. If you use a shield that increases movement speed whilst full, when stacks of Phalanx Doctrine decay you seem to gain the movement speed bonus over and over again and it stays. Problem is you definitely lose it when getting hit and you seem to lose it when entering combat (not sure how that works)? But I was killing a ton of Varkids, and after all my stacks decayed I was running at ridiculous speeds.

Comment: Sliding is faster than sprinting on flat ground. I've tested this by simply racing another player in multiplayer, and the video comparison you linked demonstrates it too, even though they're not sliding optimally. The slide is fastest at the start and slows down toward the end, so you can noticeably increase your speed by doing rapid slide cancels with  minimal time spent sprinting. In the video, a lot of the time is spent sprinting in between slides, otherwise the time difference would be greater.

Comment: Developers themselves chose to put the loading screen comment that sliding is not actually faster pretty explicitly. I'm not convinced it's faster personally either.

Comment: @n_plum The tip is probably accurate for the average player since the slide starts fast but ends slow, so you may not save any time from a single slide over just running. But since you can quickly cancel in and out of a slide to maximize the speed, it is definitely faster if you know the movement tech.

Comment: Edited the post with the information, if you could provide proof for to help support it that would be good. Feel free to edit in anything